# .innerHTML output triggered by onclick event trailing 1 event behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to calculate a total price output based on quantities selected. Even though not ideal, since I would rather have the calculation be based on the actual quantity displayed rather than its increase/decrease buttons, the onclick events right now delay the output by 1.

E.g. Let's say the price is $7.99 for a flower. I have to click on the increment button 3 times before it changes to 15.98. The decrease button acts the same in the opposite direction so that I am all of the sudden trailing one calculation behind when I decrease the quantity. Hope that makes sense.

Here are the related code bits:

```js
$(".incr-btn_mobile").on("click", function(e) {
  var $button = $(this);
  var oldValue = $button.parent().find('.quantity').val();
  $button.parent().find('.incr-btn_mobile[data-action="decrease"]').removeClass('inactive');
  if ($button.data('action') == "increase") {
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
  } else {
    // Don't allow decrementing below 1
    if (oldValue > 1) {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
    } else {
      newVal = 1;
      $button.addClass('inactive');
    }
  }
  $button.parent().find('.quantity').val(newVal);
  
  e.preventDefault();

});




function calculateTotal()
{
    //Here we get the total price by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var cakePrice = document.getElementById('ShowButton_value_1_0_mobile').value
    ;
    
    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "= $"+(cakePrice)*7.99;

}
```

```css
.count-input_mobile {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0px 0;
}

.count-input_mobile input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 36.92307692px;
  border: 1px solid #000 border-radius: 2px;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.count-input_mobile input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.count-input_mobile .incr-btn_mobile {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.count-input_mobile .incr-btn_mobile:first-child {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 46%;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-sm {
  max-width: 125px;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-sm input {
  height: 36px;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-lg {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-lg input {
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.button_mobile {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px 32px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count-input_mobile space-bottom">
  <a class="incr-btn_mobile" data-action="decrease" onclick="calculateTotal()" href="#">–</a>
  <input class="quantity" id="ShowButton_value_1_0_mobile" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" />
  <a class="incr-btn_mobile" data-action="increase" onclick="calculateTotal()" href="#">+</a>
</div>

<td>
  <div id="totalPrice">=$7.99</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing `onclick=` and `$(...).on("click")`? Do one or the other so you can control the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that the `calculateTotal` is executing before your `.on("click"` so it is picking the old value.

You actually do not need these two separate functions. You can put the below code of (`calculateTotal`) inside the `.on("click"`.

```
  var cakePrice = newVal;
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'block';
  divobj.innerHTML = "= $" + (cakePrice) * 7.99;
  e.preventDefault();
```

Se working code below.

```js
$(".incr-btn_mobile").on("click", function(e) {
  var $button = $(this);
  var oldValue = $button.parent().find('.quantity').val();
  $button.parent().find('.incr-btn_mobile[data-action="decrease"]').removeClass('inactive');
  if ($button.data('action') == "increase") {
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
  } else {
    // Don't allow decrementing below 1
    if (oldValue > 1) {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
    } else {
      newVal = 1;
      $button.addClass('inactive');
    }
  }
  $button.parent().find('.quantity').val(newVal);

  var cakePrice = newVal;
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'block';
  divobj.innerHTML = "= $" + (cakePrice) * 7.99;
  e.preventDefault();


});
```

```css
.count-input_mobile {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0px 0;
}

.count-input_mobile input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 36.92307692px;
  border: 1px solid #000 border-radius: 2px;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.count-input_mobile input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.count-input_mobile .incr-btn_mobile {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.count-input_mobile .incr-btn_mobile:first-child {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 46%;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-sm {
  max-width: 125px;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-sm input {
  height: 36px;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-lg {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-lg input {
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.button_mobile {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px 32px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count-input_mobile space-bottom">
  <a class="incr-btn_mobile" data-action="decrease" href="#">–</a>
  <input class="quantity" id="ShowButton_value_1_0_mobile" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" />
  <a class="incr-btn_mobile" data-action="increase" href="#">+</a>
</div>

<td>
  <div id="totalPrice">=$7.99</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and the explanation!

Comment: I edited the question, but still have one issue with multiple outputs.

Comment: @FatTwin this is not appreciated here in StackOverflow. If you face some doubts again after your originally posted problem gets solved then the ideal way is to mark the answer correct and post another question with your relevant doubt. Otherwise it gets hard for other people to get help from your question. Please mark this answer correct if it solves your original problem and post another question. We will help you there :) Hope you understand.

Comment: Sure thing, was not aware of this. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I edited it back to the original post and will create a new question

Comment: It says I can post a new question only every 90min. I will let you know when it's up

Comment: @FatTwin sure thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914418/interference-in-innerhtml-output-triggers